# How can I unfollow a deleted question?

Tags: support, follow-posts

In the below non-deleted questions I am following there is:

[image]

I can click "following" to unfollow the question. The deleted questions I am following are still listed in my profile at Followed posts. Below a deleted question I am following there is...

[image]

... no way to unfollow it(?).